# PHP in Commandline - Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Debug while running phpindexer.php in Magento

Tags: php, shell, magento, command-line, segmentation-fault

I'm running a script in commandline. It runs for about 5 minutes and then returns `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

The script is a Magento reindexing script. Found in /shell for those familiar with the platform

Command line script running is `php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url`

It just throws `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` - I don't know where to look for any more info than that?

Comment: How much products do you have in your database?

Comment: A touch over 26,000. Hence why I'm running the indexer through commandline and not in the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the script is running out of the memory. Magento native UrlRewrite indexer is quite slow and using a lot of memory. If you have 26k products and a lot of categories it might produce a segmentation fault.

You can try alternative Url Rewrite indexer that is using much less memory and takes much less time than core one, because performing all the operations on database level. But it requires privileges for creation and using of stored routines to work properly. Also it is strictly recommended to try it on dev environment first, to see that it will not be broken, since sometimes developers adding invalid records to core_url_rewrite table that breaking some operations.

The extension can be found by the following url:
http://www.ecomdev.org/2011/10/08/ecomdev-breaks-magento-speed-limits.html

Comment: I'd be surprised if it's running out of memory. The architecture is two dedicated web servers running magento and a dedicated database server. PHP limits etc are all set very high to reflect the set up.

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll look into the plugin.

Comment: php limits for command line can be different than limits for php within apache or ngnix. Also amount of dedicated servers doesn't resolve the out of memory possibility, since that particular indexer runs fully on php side with loading and storing of existing rewrite for checking duplicates, also it uses a lot of objects for this purpose...