# What is causing mysqli_stmt::bind_result to exit my PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bind, centos6

**EDIT 2**: I simply resorted to upgrade my PHP version to php 5.5.15. I believe the bug was with PHP itself. I found this [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66762) which seems very similar. A patch is available but I opted for a simple upgrade, not really a fix I guess.

**EDIT** : I now see `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in the cli when php hits the bind_result()

---

I am running PHP version 5.4.17 on CentOS release 6.4 (final) and whenever I run or access one of my scripts using the bind_result method the program stops at that specific line. Here is the script I am trying to run:

```
<?php
    require('./connect.php');
    global $db; //initialized in connect.php
    $username = "testuser";
    $email_in = "test@invalidemail.com";
    $db -> select_db("mydb");
    $query = "SELECT `Email`, `Password` FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = ? OR `Email` = ?";
    $result = $db->prepare($query);
    if($result->error == ""){ 
        $result->bind_param('ss', $username, $email_in);
        $result->execute();
        echo "Show before bind\n";
        try{
            echo "going in";
            $result->bind_result($dbemail, $dbpassword);        
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo "caught something";
            var_dump($e);
        }
        echo "Show after bind\n";
        $result->store_result();
        $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    }
    $result->close();
    $db->close();
?>
```

The output I get is:

```
Show before bind going in
```

And nothing else, however I have var_dumped all important variables($db $result etc) and they all see accurate and contain no errors. The funny bit is that if I change the bind_result line and put it in a var_dump, it shows that the operation returned true and the script CONTINUES!? and shows the "Show after bind"

Change that makes everything work:

```
var_dump($result->bind_result($dbemail, $dbpassword));
```

And if I revert back and use php 5.3 it works fine, and on MAMP with localhost it also works fine, even with PHP 5.4.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? If so, how did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Actually you're storing it in $numrows and you don't do anything with it.

Comment: Have you checked your PHP error log for anything?

Comment: It sounds like maybe there's a problem with your PHP 5.4 installation and it's crashing.

Comment: Should `$datenbank` be `$db` or vice versa?

Comment: @Barmar yes $datenbank is $db I just changed the name for readability, forgot that one. I think you might be right and there might be a problem with the PHP installation, I'm looking into that. I've also checked the logs, nothing.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I use it in the bigger scheme of things, I was simply using this script to isolate the problem.

Comment: did you enable `display_errors` ?

Comment: @Raptor yes display_errors is set to On

Comment: I now see a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` in the cli when php hits the bind_result

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP in Commandline - Segmentation fault (core dumped) - Debug while running phpindexer.php in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191996/php-in-commandline-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-debug-while-running-phpi)

Comment: @Raptor it might be a similar problem, however I am not using Magento. I simply resorted to upgrade my PHP version to php 5.5.15. I believe the bug was with PHP itself. I found this [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66762) which seems very similar. A patch is available but I opted for a simple upgrade, not really a fix I guess.